# I am having an xml inside xml and want to test a condition is met inside the inner xml. C# solution required

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TextType IsKey="false" Name="XMLReport"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Providers
    xmlns="Reporting"/>
    <Sales
        xmlns="Reporting"/>
        <Value
            xmlns="Reporting">
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <TestReport>
                <StudyUid>
                    <![CDATA[123]]>
                </StudyUid>
                <Modality>
                    <![CDATA[XYZ]]>
                </Modality>
                <StudyDate format="DICOM">123456</StudyDate>
                <StudyTime format="DICOM">6789</StudyTime>
                <AccessionNumber>
                    <![CDATA[123]]>
                </AccessionNumber>
                <StudyDescription>
                    <![CDATA[abc def]]>
                </StudyDescription>
                <OperatorName format="xyz">
                    <![CDATA[abc]]>
                </OperatorName>
                <PhysicianReadingStudy format="xyz">
                    <![CDATA[^^^^]]>
                </PhysicianReadingStudy>
                <InstitutionName>
                    <![CDATA[xyz]]>
                </InstitutionName>
                <HospitalName>
                    <![CDATA[Hospital Name]]>
                </HospitalName>
                <ReportSet>
                    <MyReport ID="1">
                        <ReportStatus>
                            <![CDATA[Done]]>
                        </ReportStatus>
                    </MyReport>
                    <MyReport ID="2">
                        <ReportStatus>
                            <![CDATA[Done]]>
                        </ReportStatus>
                    </MyReport>
                    <MyReport ID="3">
                        <ReportStatus>
                            <![CDATA[Initial]]>
                        </ReportStatus>
                    </MyReport>
                </ReportSet>
                <ReportImageSet />
                <FetusSet />
            </TestReport>
        </Value>
        <WhoSetMe xmlns="Reporting">NotSpecified
        </WhoSetMe>
    </TextType>
```

I want to parse the xml above in C# and check whether "ReportStatus" is "Done" for all the ReportStatus under MyReport/ReportSet. One more twist here is the xml contains one more xml starts at "Value" tag as in above example.It may contatin many ReportStatus tag under ReportSet tag. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi, I am trying something like below.But no luck

Comment: /******************************************/
            var value = xelement.Elements("Value");
            var reportStatus = xelement.Elements("ReportSet").Elements("MyReport").Select(s => s);

            var doneReortCount = reportStatus.Where(x => x.Element("ReportStatus").Value == "Done").ToList().Count;

            if (reportStatus.ToList().Count == doneReortCount)
            {
                //DO Somehing
            }
            /****************************************/

Comment: If I am able to get the xml inside value tag, I think i can get the desired result with the help of above code.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document is invalid.  You need to fix it before trying to parse it.  The issue is that a document can only have one top-level element; you have 2 `<TextType>` and `<Providers>`.

Most of your elements are the namespace `Reporting`.  You need to use it when referencing the element.

```
XNamespace ns = "Reporting";
var value = doc.Element("Value" + ns);
```

**Update**

Just use the namespace for each element

```
XNamespace ns = "Reporting";
var value = xelement.Elements("Value" + ns);
```

**Another Update**

The XML document is considered invalid because it has multiple XML declarations; there is no way to disable this.  I suggest you pre-process the document to remove the extra declarations.  Here's an example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/UnuAF6)

```
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><a> <?xml version='1.0'?><b id='b' /></a>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml.Replace(" <?xml version='1.0'?", " "));
var bs = doc.Descendants("b");
Console.WriteLine("{0} 'b' elements", bs.Count());
```

Comment: TextType is the rootnode. TextType contains child elements Providers, Sales, Value, etc. Value child node contains another xml. Is there no way to prase this xml? :(

Comment: Sorry about that, I just looked at the indentation.  To parse the XML you need to use the namespace of each element.

Comment: But when I try to parse it is complaining that the element inside Value tag is not proper. I think it is because an xml containing another xml. How can I parse and get the xml inside the Value tag?

Comment: Please tell us  the exception name and message  you are getting.  I'll respond later if no one else beats me; I'm off to the rugby.

Comment: I am getting "XMLException: - Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 11, position 7.

Comment: XElement xelement =
                XElement.Load(
                    "InputFile1.xml");
            xelement = XElement.Parse(xelement.Value);
            var xelement1 =  xelement.Elements("Value");
            var reportStatus = xelement1.Elements("ReportSet").Elements("MyReport").Select(s => s);

            var doneReortCount = reportStatus.Where(x => x.Element("ReportStatus").Value == "Done").ToList().Count;

            if (reportStatus.ToList().Count == doneReortCount)
            {
                //DO Somehing
            }

Comment: Getting the exception on XElement.Load() call

Comment: Ok, I will try your option of removing the inner XML declaration and  post the outcome. I am on travel.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Can  you try this? I tried to do it with LINQ to XML.
// I assume you have multiple <TestReport /> elements in <Value /> tag
// and var xelement is your xml variable

// First we get all TestReport elemnts
IEnumerable<XElement> allReports =  
    from el in xelement.Elements("TextType/Value/TestReport")  
    select el;

// From allReports we get all MyReport elemnts
IEnumerable<XElement> allMyReports =  
    from el in allReports.Elements("ReportSet/MyReport")  
    select el;

// From allReports we also  get all MyReport elemnts with element ReportStatus value equals "Done"
IEnumerable<XElement> allDoneMyReports =  
    from el in allMyReports  
    where (string)el.Element("ReportStatus") == "Done"  
    select el;

// Now we compare allMyReport with allDoneMyReports
if (allMyReports.Count() == allDoneMyReports.Count()) 
{ 
    //DO Somehing 
}
```